# How many droids were in the droid army and how were they paid for?

Tags: star-wars, droids

I am aware that the Galactic Senate financed the GAR through legislative bills and therefore paying for "units" of clones ([each clone costing at least 666 credits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96588/how-much-does-a-clone-cost).) One the other side, how did the Confederacy of Independent Systems finance the droids that they created? Did they also pass bills for paying for their droid armies? How many armies/units/individual droids were paid for? How much did a battle droid cost (a "unit" or a singular droid)?

I am looking for Legends or canon answers. Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong on this so I will only post a comment, but I am 99% sure that the droid army was primarily financed/supplied by the Trade Federation (TF) after Dooku convinced them to join his cause. As I recall the TF maintained a standing army of droids with the intent of protecting their goods and etc. as they traversed the systems. I am unsure how many they had in total, but I am sure the TF was wealthy enough to have a near endless supply. Others in their alliance provided other models for the army, but the bulk was from the TF. I have no clue about cost...

Comment: The [databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/confederacy-of-independent-systems) states it was the corporations that made up the CIS that funded the armies

Comment: [Cost of a droid](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134917/how-many-credits-does-1-b-1and-1-b-2-battle-droid-cost). [Which was more expensive](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82731/which-one-was-more-expensive-clone-army-or-droid-army). [How many droids](https://www.quora.com/In-the-Clone-Wars-how-much-bigger-was-the-droid-army-than-the-clone-army) (speculation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The droid armies were financed by anyone and everyone, very much like a militia force. Each member of the CIS built, funded, and contributed their droids to the army, where in they were under the command of General Grievous.

> The Separatist Droid Army was a massive, eclectic mix of droids, organic soldiers, vehicles and aircraft drawn from the various systems and corporate organizations that had declared for the Confederacy, including the Trade Federation Droid Army, the Techno Union Droid Army, the Commerce Guild Punitive Security Forces, the IGBC Collections and Security Division, and the Corporate Alliance Policy Administration Directorate.
> <sub>[Separatist Droid Army](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Separatist_Droid_Army/Legends#Organization)</sub>

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134917/how-many-credits-does-1-b-1and-1-b-2-battle-droid-cost) covers cost of droids in greater depth, but in short:

> If you consult the Role Playing Game books by George Lucas as single B1 battle droid cost 1,800 credit so you could say the army is expensive but easy to repair.
>
> So if memory is correct I think B2 battle droid were 3,000 credits. The one that cost the most was the droideka they were 21,000 credits so they were less on battlefield only for protection or used against jedi.
> <sub>[Titan84](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134918/62201)</sub>

The size of the army in Legends is the source of much speculation. Especially since it is hard to determine what is propaganda (in-universe) as opposed to fact. The CIS had millions of factories on thousands of worlds churning out droids for 5-6 years. The Battle of Geonosis featured about 1.2 million droids, and it is said by the end of the war, there were quintillions of droids in service. Remember that the CIS's strategy was to win by sheer force of numbers, so it is not unreasonable for them to have had trillions or quintillions of droids across the million or so contested worlds.

Comment: (If you upvote my answer, take a quick second to go upvote [Titan84's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134918/62201) as well)

Comment: Though that's some interesting writing. "eclectic", but we only ever see a handful of models.